# How can I install a package in R?

Tags: r, installation, package, zip

I tried to install the NHANES-RAW80Hz package in R but it does not work. The problem that indicates R is the following:

**Installing package into ‘C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open compressed file 'NHANES-RAW80Hz-0.0.3/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection.**

I think that the problem comes from a error in the .zip file, but I have contacted with the auther and she didn't reply me.
The link to download the file is: https://clevengerkimberly.github.io/2022-10-19-nhanesraw/

I tried to change the order in the .zip folder, but It did not work because the package is installed in R but when I try to active it witch the library function, the program says:
library(NHANES-RAW80Hz) : there is no package called ‘NHANES-RAW80Hz’

Someone know how can I install this package?
Thank you guys!!

Comment: try library(NHANES.RAW80Hz) . I think you spelled it wrong. Also you can try this: https://epi.grants.cancer.gov/physical/vignette.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is that I can open this package because the program says that it is not in the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error (downloaded file, using RStudio packages pane to install from zip). The error message indicates that the package in the folder is nested too deply.

- Unpack `NHANES-RAW80Hz-0.0.3.zip` to `NHANES-RAW80Hz-0.0.3`
- Navigate to subfolder `NHANES.RAW80Hz`
- Zip this subfolder -> `NHANES.RAW80Hz.zip`
- Install from this zip

Comment: Thank you micabo for your answer. I tried to do that, but the problem continues: Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

Comment: Hi jaseloga98 - could you try to detail your attempt at installing the package in some more detail (commands? clicks?) in your question? That might help to track down the error.